# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Ionic/Laravel

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

Hi I am developing a Progressive Web App using Ionic and Laravel as API provider. My Ionic app is not loading data from a remote server using angular, and shows "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.5/restful_rain_forest/public/api1.0/slide. (Reason: missing token ‘x-xsrf-token’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)".

My Angular code is as follows

```
this.http.get('http://192.168.1.5/restful_rain_forest/public/api1.0/slide').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
        this.posts = data;

    },
    err => {

        console.log("Oops!");
    });
```

Any help would be highly appriciated